# How to hide certain columns (from a table) on mobile?

Tags: html, css, web, responsive-design, html-table

I am having great problems with using tables - they look perfect on a desktop - but not on mobile.
So here's a break up of what I want to do:

- If @media screen is 600px then the number of columns = 3& the number of rows = 3
- if @media screen is 460px or less then columnCount = 2, rowCount = 4
- and columnCount = 4, rowCount =4 on desktop

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Would ``display: none`` for the non-essential columns in their respective media css help?

Comment: How about this solution? https://css-tricks.com/idea-simple-responsive-spreadsheet/

Comment: What is the percentage computability of flex layout? @JoostS

Comment: On desktop, your table should fit the screen without tweaks. On mobile you have pretty good support for strange tweaks to make it work. Therefore, this solution should do relatively well in real life. Support details are in the linked article.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Hide columns in a table using CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41221002/hide-columns-in-a-table-using-css)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hiding the second column in a table on a screen narrower than 600 pixels and additionally hiding the third column on a screen narrower than 460 pixels, goes like this:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
    tr > *:nth-child(2) {
        display: none;
    }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 460px) {
    tr > *:nth-child(3) {
        display: none;
    }
}
```

Change the column numbers to your liking (the 2 and the 3).

WARNING: I do not think this is a good solution, as a truly responsive table shows all content on all screen sizes. In general I think that content on mobile and desktop should be the same. This answer is only added to meet the exact requirements of the OP.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this nice solution on mobile from CSS tricks. This solution makes your table accessible on mobile, even is the screen is too narrow. It does NOT hide any columns (thus it makes your table truly responsive).

```css
html,body {
  margin: 20px;
  padding: 0;
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  display: flex;
  font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, "Segoe UI", Roboto, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif, "Apple Color Emoji", "Segoe UI Emoji", "Segoe UI Symbol";
  font-size: 90%;
  color: #333;
  justify-content: center;
}

.table-wrapper {
  max-width: 700px;
  overflow: scroll;
}

table {
  position: relative;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

td, th {
  white-space: nowrap;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  padding: 20px;
  text-align: center;
}

th {
  background-color: #eee;
  position: sticky;
  top: -1px;
  z-index: 2;
  
  &:first-of-type {
    left: 0;
    z-index: 3;
  }
}

tbody tr td:first-of-type {
  background-color: #eee;
  position: sticky;
  left: -1px;
  text-align: left;
}
```

```html
<div class="table-wrapper">
  <table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th></th>
      <th>A</th>
      <th>B</th>
      <th>C</th>
      <th>D</th>
      <th>E</th>
      <th>F</th>
      <th>G</th>
      <th>H</th>
      <th>I</th>
      <th>J</th>
      <th>K</th>
      <th>L</th>
      <th>M</th>
      <th>N</th>
      <th>O</th>
      <th>P</th>
      <th>Q</th>
      <th>R</th>
      <th>S</th>
      <th>T</th>
      <th>U</th>
      <th>V</th>
      <th>W</th>
      <th>X</th>
      <th>Y</th>
      <th>Z</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Anna</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>James</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Jennifer</td>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Jeremiah</td>
      <td>4</td>
      <td>4</td>
      <td>4</td>
      <td>4</td>
      <td>4</td>
      <td>4</td>
      <td>4</td>
      <td>4</td>
      <td>4</td>
      <td>4</td>
      <td>4</td>
      <td>4</td>
      <td>4</td>
      <td>4</td>
      <td>4</td>
      <td>4</td>
      <td>4</td>
      <td>4</td>
      <td>4</td>
      <td>4</td>
      <td>4</td>
      <td>4</td>
      <td>4</td>
      <td>4</td>
      <td>4</td>
      <td>4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Jocelyn</td>
      <td>5</td>
      <td>5</td>
      <td>5</td>
      <td>5</td>
      <td>5</td>
      <td>5</td>
      <td>5</td>
      <td>5</td>
      <td>5</td>
      <td>5</td>
      <td>5</td>
      <td>5</td>
      <td>5</td>
      <td>5</td>
      <td>5</td>
      <td>5</td>
      <td>5</td>
      <td>5</td>
      <td>5</td>
      <td>5</td>
      <td>5</td>
      <td>5</td>
      <td>5</td>
      <td>5</td>
      <td>5</td>
      <td>5</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Benjamin</td>
      <td>6</td>
      <td>6</td>
      <td>6</td>
      <td>6</td>
      <td>6</td>
      <td>6</td>
      <td>6</td>
      <td>6</td>
      <td>6</td>
      <td>6</td>
      <td>6</td>
      <td>6</td>
      <td>6</td>
      <td>6</td>
      <td>6</td>
      <td>6</td>
      <td>6</td>
      <td>6</td>
      <td>6</td>
      <td>6</td>
      <td>6</td>
      <td>6</td>
      <td>6</td>
      <td>6</td>
      <td>6</td>
      <td>6</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Zed</td>
      <td>7</td>
      <td>7</td>
      <td>7</td>
      <td>7</td>
      <td>7</td>
      <td>7</td>
      <td>7</td>
      <td>7</td>
      <td>7</td>
      <td>7</td>
      <td>7</td>
      <td>7</td>
      <td>7</td>
      <td>7</td>
      <td>7</td>
      <td>7</td>
      <td>7</td>
      <td>7</td>
      <td>7</td>
      <td>7</td>
      <td>7</td>
      <td>7</td>
      <td>7</td>
      <td>7</td>
      <td>7</td>
      <td>7</td>
    </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>Frank</td>
      <td>8</td>
      <td>8</td>
      <td>8</td>
     <td>8</td>
      <td>8</td>
      <td>8</td>
      <td>8</td>
      <td>8</td>
      <td>8</td>
      <td>8</td>
      <td>8</td>
      <td>8</td>
      <td>8</td>
      <td>8</td>
      <td>8</td>
      <td>8</td>
      <td>8</td>
      <td>8</td>
      <td>8</td>
      <td>8</td>
      <td>8</td>
      <td>8</td>
      <td>8</td>
      <td>8</td>
      <td>8</td>
      <td>8</td>
    </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>Chris</td>
      <td>9</td>
      <td>9</td>
      <td>9</td>
      <td>9</td>
      <td>9</td>
      <td>9</td>
      <td>9</td>
      <td>9</td>
      <td>9</td>
      <td>9</td>
      <td>9</td>
      <td>9</td>
      <td>9</td>
      <td>9</td>
      <td>9</td>
      <td>9</td>
      <td>9</td>
      <td>9</td>
      <td>9</td>
      <td>9</td>
      <td>9</td>
      <td>9</td>
      <td>9</td>
      <td>9</td>
      <td>9</td>
      <td>9</td>
    </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>Sarah</td>
      <td>10</td>
      <td>10</td>
      <td>10</td>
      <td>10</td>
      <td>10</td>
      <td>10</td>
      <td>10</td>
      <td>10</td>
      <td>10</td>
      <td>10</td>
      <td>10</td>
      <td>10</td>
      <td>10</td>
      <td>10</td>
      <td>10</td>
      <td>10</td>
      <td>10</td>
      <td>10</td>
      <td>10</td>
      <td>10</td>
      <td>10</td>
      <td>10</td>
      <td>10</td>
      <td>10</td>
      <td>10</td>
      <td>10</td>
    </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>Rob</td>
      <td>11</td>
      <td>11</td>
      <td>11</td>
      <td>11</td>
      <td>11</td>
      <td>11</td>
      <td>11</td>
      <td>11</td>
      <td>11</td>
      <td>11</td>
      <td>11</td>
      <td>11</td>
      <td>11</td>
      <td>11</td>
      <td>11</td>
      <td>11</td>
      <td>11</td>
      <td>11</td>
      <td>11</td>
      <td>11</td>
      <td>11</td>
      <td>11</td>
      <td>11</td>
      <td>11</td>
      <td>11</td>
      <td>11</td>
    </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>Danielle</td>
      <td>12</td>
      <td>12</td>
      <td>12</td>
      <td>12</td>
      <td>12</td>
      <td>12</td>
      <td>12</td>
      <td>12</td>
      <td>12</td>
      <td>12</td>
      <td>12</td>
      <td>12</td>
      <td>12</td>
      <td>12</td>
      <td>12</td>
      <td>12</td>
      <td>12</td>
      <td>12</td>
      <td>12</td>
      <td>12</td>
      <td>12</td>
      <td>12</td>
      <td>12</td>
      <td>12</td>
      <td>12</td>
      <td>12</td>
    </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>Jessica</td>
      <td>13</td>
      <td>13</td>
      <td>13</td>
      <td>13</td>
      <td>13</td>
      <td>13</td>
      <td>13</td>
      <td>13</td>
      <td>13</td>
      <td>13</td>
      <td>13</td>
      <td>13</td>
      <td>13</td>
      <td>13</td>
      <td>13</td>
      <td>13</td>
      <td>13</td>
      <td>13</td>
      <td>13</td>
      <td>13</td>
      <td>13</td>
      <td>13</td>
      <td>13</td>
      <td>13</td>
      <td>13</td>
      <td>13</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
</div>
```

Note that an a desktop your table should fit normally. On mobile it obvioulsy does not. There you need some CSS tricks to get things to work. This code makes that happen.

Source and documentation: https://css-tricks.com/idea-simple-responsive-spreadsheet/

Comment: I don't really want that - I want to change 4 columns to collapse into 2 columns

Comment: I have added another solution that does just that.